# How should I enqueue events in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a small charting library using some d3 code I've written. I've been adding configuration/customization options to my charts for various use cases, and something I keep running into is conflicting event handlers.

Transitions sometimes give me trouble, but my question is more general than that. What is a good way to execute a set of event handlers within my charts?

One method I've used is to build up a literal array of handlers, then iterate over the list, executing each handler:

```
function chart(selection) {
  selection.each(function(data) {

    // initial config and options, including the handlers array
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40},
        ...
        fadeOnHover = true,
        barMouseoutHandlers = [],
        barMouseoverHandlers = [];


    // create the chart


    // an option
    if (fadeOnHover) {
      barMousemoveHandlers.push(function(d, i) {
        selection.selectAll('.bar').filter(function(d, j){return i!=j;})
          .transition().duration(100).style('opacity', '.5');
        selection.selectAll('.bar').filter(function(d, j){return i==j;})
          .transition().duration(100).style('opacity', '1');
      });

      barMouseoutHandlers.push(function() {
        selection.selectAll('.bar').transition().duration(100).style('opacity', '1');
      });
    }

    // other options, which may add handlers

    // then at the end of the function, execute all handlers
    g.selectAll('.bar')
      .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
        barMouseoverHandlers.forEach(function(handler) { handler(d, i); });
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
        barMouseoutHandlers.forEach(function(handler) { handler(d, i); });
      });
  });
}
```

This is what I've come up when just throwing some features on my charts in the thick of things, but it clearly isn't very modular or well-organized. Perhaps there's room to extract some of these pieces into separate objects.

What other approaches are there? I would love to hear any of your thoughts on this.

Comment: Have you seen [queue](https://github.com/mbostock/queue)?

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely take a look. My question also applies to sync tasks. Basically, I'm trying to figure out how best to attach/remove multiple event listeners.

Comment: Tell us more about what you mean by 'conflicting event handlers'

Comment: I had two separate listeners to `mouseover`. First was `hoverLabel.popover('hide')`. Second was `selection.selectAll('.bar').transition().duration(100).style('opacity', '1')`. When I attached them to `g.selectAll('.layer').selectAll('.bar').on('mouseover', function...` separately, the latter stomped on the former. When I iterate over the list of handlers like in the end of my question, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to "namespace" multiple events so they do not overwrite the previously-registered event(s). Something like this:

```
g.selectAll('.bar')
  .on('mouseover.one', function(d, i) {
    // do something
  })
  .on('mouseover.two', function(d, i) {
    // something else
  });
```

From the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on):

> To register multiple listeners for the same event type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as "click.foo" and "click.bar".